# Functoriality of Kan extensions

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, kan-extensions

Consider functors $F:C\to D$ and $G:C\to C'$. It is straightforward to prove that the left [Kan extension](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Kan+extension) of $F$ along $G$, denoted by $Lan_G F$, is functorial in $F$.

How about in the argument $G$, instead? I'm looking for a statement in the following form.

> Let $\phi:G\to G'$ be a natural transformation between functors $G,G':C\to C'$. We can obtain canonically a natural transformation $Lan_{G'}F\to Lan_G F$ between functors $C'\to D$.

Note the direction of the arrow, I expect a *contravariant* functor.

If this holds, I'm sure it has been done somewhere. Where can I find a reference?

Comment: There is no reference that I am aware of, but doing the math isn't difficult, isn't it?

Comment: Ah, I was sure I had done the maths ;) 
You could have quoted "[coend](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1501.02503.pdf)" 2.3.2, but unfortunately there is a small typo (the typing of the functor is incorrect, of course: it should be $Cat(C,E)^{op} \to Cat(Cat(C,D),Cat(E,D))$). The typo is absent from the most updated version, and _as far as I can foresee_ will be 2.3.2 also in the printed copy. But I can't ensure that :) if you just want a reference, I guess "[Coend, Chap. 2]" will do